# Libgdx: Different positions using BitmapFont

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I encountered a problem within my (very) simple project. When I draw text, it is displayed in a different position (and appareantly with different size) between Android (Samsung Galaxy S Advance) and Desktop.

In my renderer class I have:

```
private OrthographicCamera cam;
public final int WIDTH  = 320;
public final int HEIGHT = 480;

private ShapeRenderer debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
private SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
private BitmapFont font;
```

And in my constructor:

```
MyClass(){
    this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.cam.position.set(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, 0);
    this.cam.update();
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/font.fnt"));

    font.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Finally, the render function:

```
public void render() {
     // For each block y use this code:
     // debugRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

     // Rectangle rect = block.getBounds();
     // debugRenderer.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
     // debugRenderer.end();

     // And then I draw my text:

     batch.begin();

     font.draw(batch, "Score: " + world.getScore(), 50,50)
     batch.end();
}
```

All block dimensions are in absolute numbers (not relative to any variable like stage.getWidth() or something like that).

The result in Desktop is the following: 
[image: Desktop appearance]

While in Android I have:
[image: Android appearance]

As you may see, blocks have the same distribution along the screen (in terms of % of screen covered), while text doesn't. It doesn't start in the same place and doesn't have the same height.

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Just in case it helps, blocks bounds are:

```
XPos: 45 * i
YPos: 45 * j
SizeX: 32
SizeY: 32
```

EDIT: Another consideration, the font I'm using is extracted from: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos/superjumper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `this.cam.update();` do you do -

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(this.cam.combined);
debugRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(this.cam.combined);
```